# Problema con conexión y consulta a base de datos

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

[image: UML]
Buenas tardes, estoy teniendo problemas con la conexión y la consulta a la base de datos, adjunto UML y codigo.

Caso de uso
Las operaciones que se desea que los mecánicos puedan realizar son las descritas en los siguientes casos:
Mecánico    -> Registra trabajo.

1. El mecánico selecciona la opción “Registra trabajo”.
2. La app muestra una ventana que permita introducir el tipo de trabajo y su descripción.
3. El mecánico introduce los datos.
4. La app añade el trabajo a la lista de trabajos registrados y muestra el identificador asignado al trabajo.

Clase Materiales

```
package com.mycompany.garaje;

import java.awt.Menu;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Maite
 ConectarBD()
 DesconectarDB()
 execute()
 getData()
 agregar()
 agregar (ArrayList)
 eliminar
 modificar
 Consultar (String nombre, precio)
 Consulta (material)
 Consultar ()
 */
public class Materiales {
    private int idMaterial;
    private String descripcionMaterial;
    private float precioMaterial;
    private float cantidad;
    public Materiales(int idMaterial, String descripcionMaterial, float precioMaterial, float cantidad){
        this.idMaterial=idMaterial;
        this.descripcionMaterial=descripcionMaterial;
        this.precioMaterial=precioMaterial;
        this.cantidad=cantidad;
    }

    public int getIdMaterial() {
        return idMaterial;
    }

    public void setIdMaterial(int idMaterial) {
        this.idMaterial = idMaterial;
    }

    public String getDescripcionMaterial() {
        return descripcionMaterial;
    }

    public void setDescripcionMaterial(String descripcionMaterial) {
        this.descripcionMaterial = descripcionMaterial;
    }

    public float getPrecioMaterial() {
        return precioMaterial;
    }

    public void setPrecioMaterial(float precioMaterial) {
        this.precioMaterial = precioMaterial;
    }

    public float getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(float cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
    
    public void agregarMaterial (Materiales material){
        if(conectarBD()){
            String sql="Insert into materiales (descripcionMaterial)";
            sql+="(descripcionMaterial,precio) values ('";
            sql+=material.getDescripcionMaterial() + "',";
            sql+=material.getPrecioMaterial()+")";
            
        }
        
    }
    public void agregarListaMateriales(ArrayList listaMateriales){
            ArrayList<material> listaMateriales;
            
        
    }

   private static boolean conectarBD(DriverManager cn) throws ClassNotFoundException{
       //Cargar el Driver de jdbc. Genera una excepción si no se encuentra dicho driver
       Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
       //Crear el objeto Connection
       cn = DriverManager.getConnection(SERVIDOR, USER, PASSWORD);
       //Devolver true si es exitosa
       return true;
        
    }
    private static void desconectarBD() throws SQLException{
      ;
        if(!cn.isClosed() && cn!=null){
            cn.close();
        }
    }
    private static String getData(String sql){
         String cabecera="Listado de todos los datos";
         cabecera+="---------------------------------";
            try {
                //Objeto Statement para ejecutar la consulta
                Statement sentencia=cn.createStatement();
                //Objeto Resultset
                ResultSet rs=sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
                for(int c=1;c<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();c++){
                    cabecera+=rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(c)+"\t";
                }
                cabecera+="\n";
                //Leer Todas las Filas de datos
                while(rs.next()){
                    for(int c=1;c<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();c++){
                         cabecera+=rs.getString(c);
                    }
                cabecera+="\n"; 
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        return cabecera;
    }
private static int execute(String sql){
    int registros = 0;
            try {
                sentencia = cn.createStatement();
                registros=sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
   
    return registros;
 }
   }
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes?, ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Segundo intento. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta puntual?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Creo que otra manera de hacer eso es con una clase de conexión a la base y luego instancias esa clase y realizas la conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrias crear una clase de conexión a la base de datos

```
package com.app.sockets.conexion;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datos";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static Conexion instancia;
    
    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    }

    public void cerrarResultado(ResultSet resultado) {
        try {
            resultado.close();
        } catch (SQLException error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }

    public void desconectar(Connection conexion) {
        try {
            conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }

    public void cerrarStatement(PreparedStatement statement) {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }
    
    public static Conexion getInstance(){
        if(instancia == null){
            instancia = new Conexion();
        }
        return instancia;
    }
}
```

y luego esta clase la llamas donde quieres manejar el sql

```
package com.app.sockets.controlador;

import com.app.sockets.conexion.Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ing.mateo
 */
public class Controlador {
    private Conexion conectar;
    private Connection con;
    
    public Controlador(){
    conectar = new Conexion();
    }
    
    public void insertarCargo(String nombre ,int cargo_sueldo_minimo,int cargo_sueldo_maximo){
        PreparedStatement ps;
        String sql;
        
        try{
            con = conectar.conectar();
            sql = "insert into cargo(cargo_nombre,cargo_sueldo_minimo,cargo_sueldo_maximo) values(?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, nombre);
            ps.setInt(2, cargo_sueldo_minimo);
            ps.setInt(3, cargo_sueldo_maximo);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("exito");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```